# Anyway possible I can speed up adding very large textfile data into AutoComplete ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, io, stream

Making a little program for myself which has to do with movies/tv shows. Currently I have all movies formatted into a txt file. A movie title per line.

This txt file has a gigantic range of movies (Over 100MB) and I have a AutoComplete ComboBox. (Suggests auto-completion of movie name to user).

The Code I use now:

```
private void addComboBox()
    {
        try
        {

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("movies.txt"))
            {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    String editline = line.TrimStart();
                    //System.Console.WriteLine(editline);                                         
                    movies.Items.Add(editline);

                }
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Error opening the file of movies! " + e);
        }
    }
```

Now with code it takes roughly 20 seconds to actually start up the program and when typing the movie in it's quiet sluggish. (Guess that will happen with 2.7million lines of names)

Are there any better ways of doing this? Don't think I've seen a problem exactly the same as mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to import this data to a table on any database. So you can take advantage of indexes that is so much FAST.

If you need a more scalabe and fast approach you can try specific text indexed databases, such as Cassandra, Dynamo, Mongo, ElasticSearch and others.

But in a simple scenario I believe you will win so much if you use any database, even if you choose Access or SQLite.

You can also try some algorithm such as Binary Trees or HashTables, or surf the Google to look for "the best text search algorithm", but in a real world I will run up a database.

After, you only have to make async calls to get a limited list (ie first 20) and dinamically load options.

Comment: If I was to use a database are there easy ways to actually insert 2.7mill names into a table?  And will databases you mentioned be fully compatible with ComboBox C#? I'm familiar with mySQL/SQLite. I've never used Algorithms in a program before so I know it will take a very long time to implement into my program. if you have a good guide that solves a problem similar to mine, that will be great.

Comment: With MySQL you can use Workbench. Just create a table with one text field, right click on it and choose "Table Data Import Wizard" and you can do it in few minutes. After, you will have to connect your application to this database, but it is another chapter to discuss, ok.

Comment: The problem here is not data source. the problem is Combobox. If you load all line of text using System.IO.File.ReadAllLines you will see it load all of data very quick but when adding to combobox and when autocompelete problem shows its face.

Comment: I don't recommend following database or datatable approaches since the System.IO.File.ReadAllLine is quick enough and also You can then search in the loaded array very very quickly.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I believe you never can have over 100MB of string as options of a combobox, and expect it will be fast. At least, not at this year (2015), on a reasonable PC. So I have indicated the database way, that seems to be much more viable.

Comment: @RezaAghaei This was my first initial plan. Getting all the names in an Array however wouldn't doing that with AutoComplete be incredibly slow? 2.7mill names in an Array seems like the program will just crash? Would it be as simple as ReadAllLines/Array or do I have to do anything else?

Comment: @rkawano Olay, will try using MySQL. Thanks.

Comment: @rkawano I See, and as I said, the problem is with combo box not with the text file.

Comment: @bob9123 I recommend you change your approach of auto complete. for example, you can fill items of combo box this way: when user types in combobox, load top 50 movies starting with the string user typed and set as combobox items, this way cost of adding items to combobox it very low. -- you should be aware that using a database will not solve the problem at all.

Comment: So will this be using ReadAllLines/Array? Directly searching for 50 movie names in an Array? Please can you supply example code

Answer (score 0):

An option is to set your datasource to SQL database - maybe SQLite to keep it local and simple or implement a efficient search algorithm, such as [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: Do you have a good guide for Trie that does something similar to my problem? I'm probably going to use mySQL. Hopefully it will work with my situation.